# Fast ways to generate multiple sequences without using for loop in Matlab

Tags: matlab, for-loop, sequences

Suppose, I have two arrays:

```
startIds = [x1, x2, x3]
endIds = [y1, y2, y3]
```

The two arrays have the same length and can be long. We may assume that (endIds(ii)-startIds(ii)) are the same for all positions ii. Is there any fast ways to generate multiple sequences without using for loop?

```
startIds(1):endIds(1)
startIds(2):endIds(2)
startIds(3):endIds(3)
```

Thanks!

-Thang

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the fastest answer I got through Mathworks:

```
range = endIds(1) - startIds(1);
t3 = bsxfun(@plus, startIds(:), 0:range);
```

At the time of this writing, this is the only version that is faster than my for loop version, which is in turn faster than using arrayfun or ndgrid. See my detailed benchmark here:
http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/217205-fast-ways-to-generate-multiple-sequences-without-using-for-loop

Answer (score 2):

You can use `arrayfun`:

```
sequences = arrayfun(@(i, j) (i:j), startIds, endIds, 'un', 0);
```

You will get a cell array `sequences`, where `sequences{k} = startIds(k):endIds(k)`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Sorry that I wasn't clear that I'm looking for solutions that are faster than using for loop. See the solutions I found through Mathworks!

Answer (score 1):

You may also try having some fun with matrices,

First get the difference between each entry and the first one in startIds,

```
dif = startIds - startIds(1);
dif_m = repmat(dif,endIds-startIds+1,1);
```

Then make a matrix of your first sequence

```
multi_seq = repmat((startIds(1):endIds(1))',1,length(startIds));
```

Get the sequences,

```
multi_seq = multi_seq + dif_m;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! As with my comment for the answer above, my apology for not making it clear that I'm looking for solutions that are faster than using for loop. Check out the answer I found from Mathworks!